# learning ecma script/javascript directly from the reference

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn Javascript.There are some excellent books and great authors that became standard in JS world - As I can see, they all have their own way of interpretation of language. It can be sometimes confusing for the novice in Javascript.I wonder, how usefull can be to learn directly from ECMAScript language specification as it was published by the authors of the language ?

Comment: Depends on how skilled you are with programming and how many other specifications you've read. Of course you may be better of reading the good parts instead

Comment: Agreed, Douglas Crockford ( http://javascript.crockford.com/ ) and folks who've done work based on his are pretty good resources. Most likely more helpful than the ECMAscript specification.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably much better to learn from the tutorials, as the specification is designed for people implementing JavaScript parsers/interpreters, not for people learning JavaScript itself.

If you want to learn from a reference, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a fantastic resource. There are also plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Please don't recommend tizag, it's written (or looks like it's written) in the time when javascript was used only to annoy people with alerts. It's also bad for mostly the same reasons w3schools is bad

Comment: @Esailija Edited. I've used Tizag as a quick and dirty PHP/MySQL reference and I assumed their JS stuff was of similar (alright) quality, but having not used their JS stuff I didn't know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The specification is optimized for defining the language from the point of view of its implementors. It is not optimized for teaching it to someone that is new to the language.

A good learning reference has also many things that are not covered in the language spec, like common APIs (like the DOM and a JS framework) and common patterns (ex.: the module pattern, namespaces, etc...). While it is true that some people might have some coding practices you don't agree with you should not immetiately dismiss what they say, unless you really want to learn everything and fall into every trap yourself. As long as you have a mental framework of what you consider to be the best practices in general you should be able to identify what you agree with or not.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is one of the most controversial languages in existence, there is no clear author and no clear documentation.

The best project I know of is **[Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)**, it's pretty extensive and comprehensive.

Comment: There is a clear author, it's called TC39. There is a clear documentation, it's called the ES specification